# Haskell: Catching exceptions from Data.Binary.Get

Tags: exception, haskell

I've got the following code:

```
import Data.Binary.Get
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import qualified Control.Exception as E

main = do
    let dat = L.pack [1,2,3,4]
    E.catch (E.evaluate $ runGet getWord32be dat) (\_ -> return 0) (return 1)
    putStrLn "Done"
```

I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `m1 t -> m a'
       against inferred type `IO GHC.Word.Word32'
In a stmt of a 'do' expression:
    E.catch
      (E.evaluate $ runGet getWord32be dat) (\ _ -> return 0) (return 1)
```

But I can't figure out what's the mismatch. Can someone enlighten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch only takes two arguments. You're giving it three.